# MS SQL get aggregate datetime difference by status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table in sql.

```
======================================================
UnitID    Status         DateTime              Value
======================================================
 101        A       01/12/2017 00:02:10          10
 101        A       01/12/2017 00:02:40          25
 101        A       01/12/2017 00:03:20          18
 101        B       01/12/2017 00:03:55          30
 101        B       01/12/2017 00:04:05          10
 101        B       01/12/2017 00:04:30          20
 101        B       01/12/2017 00:04:50          10
 101        A       01/12/2017 00:05:00          28
 101        A       01/12/2017 00:05:50          18
 101        A       01/12/2017 00:06:20          18
 102        A       01/12/2017 00:02:10          10
 102        A       01/12/2017 00:02:40          25
 102        A       01/12/2017 00:03:20          18
 102        B       01/12/2017 00:03:55          30
 102        B       01/12/2017 00:04:05          10
 102        B       01/12/2017 00:04:30          20
 102        B       01/12/2017 00:04:50          10
 102        A       01/12/2017 00:05:00          28
 102        A       01/12/2017 00:05:50          18
 102        A       01/12/2017 00:06:20          18
```

From this table i need below mention output.

```
===========================================
UnitID    StatusA     StatusB    MaxValue
===========================================
 101       02:30       00:55       30
 102       02:30       00:55       30
```

what i need is the total time difference by status. so how could i achieve this in mssql query. so here 02:30 is time duration for status "A" in the table.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you need with the following query. I tried to separate each step on different CTE's so you can see step by step how to get to your result. `LAG` will retrieve the previous row value (spliting by the `PARTITION BY` columns and ordering by the `ORDER BY`).

```
;WITH LaggedValues AS
(
    SELECT
        M.UnitID,
        M.Status,
        M.DateTime,
        LaggedDateTime = LAG(M.DateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY M.UnitID ORDER BY M.DateTime ASC),
        LaggedStatus = LAG(M.Status) OVER (PARTITION BY M.UnitID ORDER BY M.DateTime ASC)
    FROM
        Measures AS M
),
TimeDifferences AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        SecondDifference = CASE 
            WHEN T.Status = T.LaggedStatus THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, T.LaggedDateTime, T.DateTime) END
    FROM
        LaggedValues AS T
),
TotalsByUnitAndStatus AS
(
    SELECT
        T.UnitID,
        T.Status,
        SecondDifference = SUM(T.SecondDifference)
    FROM
        TimeDifferences AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.UnitID,
        T.Status
),
TotalsByUnit AS -- Conditional aggregation (alternative to PIVOT)
(
    SELECT
        T.UnitID,
        StatusA = MAX(CASE WHEN T.Status = 'A' THEN T.SecondDifference END),
        StatusB = MAX(CASE WHEN T.Status = 'B' THEN T.SecondDifference END)
    FROM
        TotalsByUnitAndStatus AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.UnitID
)
SELECT
    T.UnitID,
    StatusA = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.StatusA / 60) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.StatusA % 60),
    StatusB = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.StatusB / 60) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.StatusB % 60)
FROM
    TotalsByUnit AS T
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cannot have status in different columns, only by row.

```
SELECT [UnitID], [Status], MAX([DateTime]) - MIN([DateTime]), MAX([Value])
FROM [theTable]
GROUP BY [UnitID], [Status]
```

Output would be like

```
101 A 02:30 30
101 B 00:55 30
102 A 02:30 30
102 B 00:55 30
```

If you have fixed states of A and B you can go messy and do this:

```
SELECT UnitID, A, B, MaxValue
FROM
(
SELECT [UnitID], MAX([DateTime]) - MIN([DateTime]) AS A, null AS B, MAX([Value]) AS MaxValue
FROM [theTable]
WHERE Status = 'A'
GROUP BY [UnitID]
UNION ALL
SELECT [UnitID], null, MAX([DateTime]) - MIN([DateTime]), MAX([Value])
FROM [theTable]
WHERE Status = 'B'
GROUP BY [UnitID]
) x
```

Comment: He isn't doing max - min, he is doing difference against previous record by time and status. You can have different status in different column by using pivot.

Comment: @EzLo did not know about "pivot" before but looks nice. Just learnt something new. Thanks!

Comment: yes @Ezlo i want calculate the difference between date against previous record. But i have the fixed number of status too. Using pivot we can prepare the columns by status but i don't know how to calculate the difference between records.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the difference for each group:

```
select unitid, status, min(datetime) as mindt, max(datetime) as maxdt, max(value) as maxvalue
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by unitid order by datetime) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by unitid, status order by datetime) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by unitid, status, (seqnum - seqnum_s);
```

This solves the "groups-and-islands" problem.  Now you can get the information you want using conditional aggregation:

```
with t as (
      select unitid, status, min(datetime) as mindt, max(datetime) as maxdt, max(value) as maxvalue
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by unitid order by datetime) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by unitid, status order by datetime) as seqnum_s
            from t
           ) t
      group by unitid, status, (seqnum - seqnum_s)
     )
select unitid,
       sum(case when status = 'A' then datediff(minute, mindt, maxdt) end) as a_minutes,
       sum(case when status = 'b' then datediff(minute, mindt, maxdt) end) as a_minutes,
       max(maxvalue)
from t
group by unitid;
```

I'll leave it up to you to convert the minutes back to times.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff your solution is also work for me. but Ezlo describe it in detail so i mark it a right answer.

Comment: @ronak . . . That is a more complicated query in my opinion.